Flutter with Firebase Real Time Databases
I'm new to Firebase Real Time Databases.
In my Flutter App I'm trying to set up a connection to my database but unfortunately I can't fetch any data. From my knowledge I set everything up as it's supposed to be, but maybe I'm missing something.
This is my current setup of the database. The data should be correct since I already use regular Firestore databases in the same project:
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: 'myKey',
      appId: 'myAppId',
      messagingSenderId: 'senderId',
      projectId: 'xyz',
      storageBucket: 'xyz',
    ),
  );

Here I try to query my data (returns null):
final FirebaseDatabase _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
DatabaseReference usersRef = _database.ref('users/user1');

usersRef.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
    final data = event.snapshot.value;
});

This is my data in the real time database:
{
  "users": {
    "user1": {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 37.7749,
        "longitude": -122.4194
      },
      "username": "User 1"
    },
    "user2": {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 40.7128,
        "longitude": -74.006
      },
      "username": "User 2"
    }
  }
}

I already checked the permissions in my real time database and for my test purposes I set them to allow all.
Am I missing something?

"(returns null)" Nothing in the code seems to return anything. Can you edit the code and your question to make the problem clearer? E.g. can you add a print statement that outputs something different than you expect, and show us that code and its output? (I also recommend checking out How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example, as it's a great guide on how to help us help you most efficiently).
